# outOfMemory java heap space error on tomcat server, not appearing locally

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I'm building a web-site using Java Spring and Hibernate and using Tomcat 7 as server.
I have a page of this site where, once the user clicks on an image other two images are loaded. The workflow is the following:

Image Clicked -> Calculation(spring method) -> Images saved on the server as jpg -> Images updated from the server and showed to the client.

The images are loaded like follows:

```
    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();  
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(xzCrossUrl);  
    int size = in.available();  
    byte[] content = new byte[size];  
    in.read(content);  
    out.write(content);  
    in.close();  
    out.close();
```

I know this probably is not the best way to doing it, but I have not much experience yet.

Locally it works fine, but when I put the .war on the tomcat directory and connect to the server, a Java outOfMemory heap space problem is coming out, and the images are loaded much slower than locally.

I tried to increase the memory used by tomcat but it seems not to work; maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Can you please help me with this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try these steps told here first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718786/how-to-increase-java-heap-space-for-a-tomcat-app

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried to increase tomcat heap space previously but it didn't fix the problem. I will try to install jprofile as soon as possibile and let you know

Answer (score 1):

I can't put this in a comment because I don't have enough cred, so...

While it may be something you can fix with the Tomcat configuration, what code you have will not scale for any image.  You should declare the `byte[]` to be a fixed size and then read and write until you've consumed all of the file bytes:

`// as a class scoped constant

    private static final int BUFFERSIZE = 1024 << 8;`

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), BUFFERSIZE);
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(xzCrossUrl));  
int bytesRead = 0;
byte[] content = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];  
while((bytesRead = in.read(content) != -1){
   out.write(content,0,bytesRead);
}
// Don't forget appropriate exception handling with a try/finally!
in.close();  
out.close();
```

FYI:  I wrote this here, not in an IDE and have not compiled it, so my apologies if isn't perfect.  Hopefully you get the gist.

Comment: Thank for your answer. You have missed a bracket in the while but it's ok :) 
Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem.
I'm starting to think that the problem is in the computation part concering the images.
I don't know if the problem could be in the configuration of the server too.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `IOUtils.copy()` from the Apache Commons IO package - which will copy the input stream to the output stream and will buffer internally so you don't have to.

```
response.setContentType("image/jpg");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();  
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(xzCrossUrl);  
IOUtils.copy(in, out);

IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
```

For larger files you can use `IOUtils.copyLarge()`

For more info on Commons IO see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but this didn't solve my problem :( Maybe the issue is not in the loading of the images