# Java application and tomcat suddenly stops without apparent reason

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, jvm, heap-memory

I am using **Jpedal** tool to convert PDF to Image. Jpedal tool helps to convert any or large number of PDF pages (let's say PDF pages = 1200) into .PNG images. In general this is working, however once in a while during converting these large number of PDF pages into images it causes the application and tomcat to stop without any information or logs.

It seems it's simply an **OutOfMemoryError** that is not being printed. While processing it prints the line **logger.info("width = "+ width + "   height= "+height);** multiple times but at some point exits after that and stops tomcat.
Can anyone please help what to do for the same.
My Code: -

```
public boolean createPDF2ImageTask(String sourcePDFAbsPath, String destinationImageAbsPath, Float scalingFactor, String fileFormat, int softLimitInKB) throws Exception
{ 

System.setProperty("org.jpedal.flattenForm","true");
logger.info("createPDF2ImageTask ( sourcePDFAbsPath = "+sourcePDFAbsPath+" , destinationImageAbsPath = "+destinationImageAbsPath+ ", scalingFactor = "+scalingFactor+ " , fileFormat = "+fileFormat+ " softLimitInKB ="+softLimitInKB );
boolean status = true;
Float newScalingFactor;
int sizeOfImageInKB;

//PdfDecoder object provides the conversion 

PdfDecoderServer decoder = null;
Map mapValues = null;
BufferedImage imageToSave = null;
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
try
{

    Helper.deleteFile(destinationImageAbsPath);

    //mappings for non-embedded fonts to use
    FontMappings.setFontReplacements();

    decoder = new PdfDecoderServer(true);
    decoder.openPdfFile(sourcePDFAbsPath);


    mapValues = new HashMap();


    mapValues.put(JPedalSettings.EXTRACT_AT_BEST_QUALITY_MAXSCALING, 2);

    //alternatively secify a page size (aspect ratio preserved so will do best fit)
    //set a page size (JPedal will put best fit to this)
    PdfPageData pageData = decoder.getPdfPageData();
    int width = (int)(scalingFactor*pageData.getCropBoxWidth(1));
    int height = (int)(scalingFactor*pageData.getCropBoxHeight(1));
    logger.info("width = "+ width + "   height= "+height);          
    mapValues.put(JPedalSettings.EXTRACT_AT_PAGE_SIZE, new String[]{String.valueOf(width),String.valueOf(height)});

    //which takes priority (default is false)
    mapValues.put(JPedalSettings.PAGE_SIZE_OVERRIDES_IMAGE, Boolean.TRUE);

    PdfDecoderServer.modifyJPedalParameters(mapValues);                              

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    try
    {
        imageToSave = decoder.getPageAsHiRes(1, null, false);
        decoder.flushObjectValues(true);
        if(imageToSave != null)
        {
            logger.info("Start saving image as a file");
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationImageAbsPath)));

            ImageIO.write(imageToSave, fileFormat, bufferedOutputStream);

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("imageToSave is null, Exception in extractPageAsImage ");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception in extractPageAsImage :: "+e);
        logger.error("Exception stack trace in extractPageAsImage :: ",e);
        throw new Exception("Exception in extractPageAsImage :: "+e);
    }
```

Comment: based on the information you have given, an out of memory error seems like a bold guess. what is your  theory based on?

Comment: @loonytune
Occasionally, an application might crash soon after an allocation failure from the native heap. This occurs if you’re running native code that doesn’t check for errors returned by memory allocation functions.

For example, the malloc system call returns NULL if there is no memory available. If the return from malloc is not checked, then the application might crash when it attempts to access an invalid memory location. Depending on the circumstances, this type of issue can be difficult to locate.

Comment: Also this issue is coming for large files only, I read an article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718786/how-to-increase-java-heap-space-for-a-tomcat-app it says, this error either happens right away with a large file and then you can increase memory still further, or investigate find out why so much memory is needed for one file.

Comment: ok, that is true. but in this case you are allocating into native memory, and this has nothing to do with the JVM, giving you no possibility to check or guard against that in Java Code.  But in this case there might also just be an invalid pointer dereference. In native code, a ton of things could make you crash. Still, although i cannot rule it out, I see "special indication" that this might be a memory problem, especially not if you bring native code into this ...

Comment: @loonytune : I see this might be a memory problem. Maybe we could try to solve this by increasing memory of our Tomcat instance.

Comment: that you "see this as a memory problem" is not evidence, not even a good hint!

Comment: @loonytune : I have increased the JVM heap memory for tomcat to -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" 
but still it stops tomcat. 
Can you please help for the same

Comment: your latest comment is a hint that it is not a memory problem. I'm not a tomcat specialist, but try to enable full log detail and you may also play around with the -verbose flag of the VM. Maybe this will get you some more insight. You can also try to build logging into your own code to see at what line exactly tomcat stops. if it is indeed a memory problem, it might show up with -verbose:gc, although i doubt it