# Java.lang.OutOfMemory not solved when change the setenv.sh file in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I used Tomcat 7 for deploy the applications. I execute below code for get the OutOfMemory error.

```
Long maxMemorySize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
model.addAttribute("memorySize",maxMemorySize);
int[] matrixArr = new int[(int) (maxMemorySize + 1)];
for(int i = 0; i < matrixArr.length; ++i)
    matrixArr[i] = i+1;
```

After error is appear, I create a setenv.sh file in tomcat/bin and add below code in it.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"
```

Then restart the Tomcat server and re-execute the programme. But again OutOfMemory error appear. 
I change the parameters of CATALINA_OPTS, but it doesn't work. And also add below code in setenv.sh file, but it also doesn't work.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase Java heap space for a tomcat app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718786/how-to-increase-java-heap-space-for-a-tomcat-app)

Comment: I think you're using the wrong parameter to be designated as the **max allocatable** heap size. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-are-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` return the maximum amount of memory that JVM will attempt to use.
It return `1024M` when `-Xmx1024M`. The array `matrixArr` need to allocate `1024M*4` of memory. That's why you still got `java.lang.OutOfMemory` exception after increasing JVM heap size.

Comment: Thanx @beckyang. This is helps me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't allocate all the memory in a Java VM.  It needs room for the program code, class definitions and static fields in many classes that get loaded.

Furthermore, you're allocating an array of ints (which are 4 bytes per piece) while your `maxMemory` returns a value in bytes.

So if `maxMemory` returns 100, then you try to allocate an array of 100 ints, which at the very minimum requires 400 bytes of space.

What you can do is use `IntBuffer.allocateDirect` to allocate space outside the Java heap.

Answer (score 0):

if your tomcat server is running on a linux machine and installed from repository the do this .. edit /etc/default/tomcat7. in the line JAVA_OPTS replace the value for **-Xmx** with **(2048m)**. leave everything else the same. restart tomcat