# How to increase Maximum Memory Pool Size? Apache Tomcat 9

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, geoserver

I am trying to increase my Maximum memory pool in Apache tomcat `config`.

I am using Geo-server services with the help of Apache, however my memory in Geo-server is filling very fast. All the time I have to free memory from Geo-server Server Status.

I have to increase my memory to `2048 maximum` by stopping Apache server when I increase from `1024 to 2048` Apache is not starting.

Can anyone guide me what to do how I should increase my memory size?

[image]

Comment: "When I increase from 1024 to 2048 apache is not starting." well do you have enough memory to give 2GB for Tomcat?

Comment: I have 2TB memory space on my Drive. Where Apache and geoserver are installed.

Comment: "2TB memory space on my Drive" what does that mean? Do you understand the difference between memory and disk storage?

Comment: Kayaman sorry i was thinking about disk storage.

Comment: I got solution ... I just install 64 bit java...

Answer (score 5):

32bit programs have a severe memory limitation (from -my- ancient memory: The limit is around 1.5G on Windows, provided it's started early after the OS started). This stems from the requirement of the JVM to get contiguous memory, of which there's not enough available in the 32bit subsystem. According to the screenshot, you're running a 32bit JVM (because it's installed in "Program Files (x86)") on a 64bit Operating System.

Install (and use) a 64bit JVM and make sure that you have enough memory available.

My recommendation is to set the "Initial memory pool" to the same value as the "Maximum memory pool", so that you discover memory problems while you start the service, and not sunday nights at 3am, when the JVM tries to allocate the rest of the memory but can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum memory pool size is the maximum allocated memory for tomcat depending on available main memory(RAM)